# Install Miniconda on top of Anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, miniconda

I have recently installed Python with Anaconda and started learning Python using these. However, I am starting an analytics course and the textbook states to start the process by installing Miniconda first and then Anaconda second. Will there be any issue if I install Miniconda with already having Anaconda installed?

Read other articles here and the answers weren't clear to whether this would be an issue.

Comment: If you already have Anaconda, you can create a new environment that mimics miniconda by writing `conda create -n new-env python=3`

Comment: Excellent. Thank you @darthbith!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have Anaconda, you can create a new environment that mimics miniconda by writing

```
conda create -n new-env python=3
```